# Hacer aparecer/desaparecer un div cuando hago scroll

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo hacer con `JS` para que cuando haga scroll hacia abajo desaparezca el div=Ventana?

¿Y si hago scroll hacia arriba que aparezca?

```css
#Ventana {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#OtroContenedor {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="Ventana">
  Esto es mi ventana
</div>

<div id="OtroContenedor">
  Este texto es de relleno
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluando hacia donde va el scroll y utilizando la propiedad CSS 'display':

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       document.getElementById("Ventana").style.display = "none"
   } else {
      // upscroll code
      document.getElementById("Ventana").style.display = "inline"
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener el alto y posicion del `div Ventana`, luego detectar la posicion del `scrollTop` y comparar:

**Solucion**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 //var altoVentana = $('#Ventana').css('height').replace("px","");//usa este para que desaparezca despues de pasar el alto del div
 var altoVentana = 0;
 var posicionVentana = document.getElementById("Ventana").offsetTop;
 $(window).scroll(function(event){
  var posicionScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (posicionScroll > (parseInt(posicionVentana)+parseInt(altoVentana))){
      $("#Ventana").css("display","none");
     } else {
      $("#Ventana").css("display","");
     }

 });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#Ventana {height: 100px;width: 100%;background-color: red;text-align: center;line-height: 100px;}
#OtroContenedor {height: 1500px;width: 100%;background-color: purple;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Ventana">Esto es mi ventana</div>
<div id="OtroContenedor">Este texto es de relleno</div>
</body>
</html>
```